# Suddenly pdf doesn't upload anymore (php/mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, upload

I just registered cause I have a problem suddenly with code that worked perfectly so far and I have found some very good answers on here before. Hope you guys can help me again, this time even for a vote ;)

```
$sql='SELECT projektKurz, projektTitelGer, projektTitelEng, projektTitelFr
FROM projects 
WHERE PNO=?';

$statement=$mysqli->prepare($sql);
//  FEHLERBEHANDLUNG
//  var_dump($statement);
//  echo "<br />";
//  var_dump($mysqli->error);
$statement->bind_param("i", $PNO);
$statement->execute();
$statement->bind_result($projektKurz,$projektTitelGer,$projektTitelEng,$projektTitelFr);
$statement->fetch();
$statement->store_result();
$statement->free_result();

$report="";
$allowedExts = array("xls", "xlsx", "doc", "docx", "ppt", "pptx", "pdf", "zip", "rar", "gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png", "bmp");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/vnd.ms-excel")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/msword")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/pdf")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/x-pdf")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/acrobat")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/vnd.pdf")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "text/pdf")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "text/x-pdf")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/force-download")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/x-octet-stream")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/zip")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/x-rar-compressed")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/bmp"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 100000000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    $report .= "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
  else
    {
    $report .= "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />
    Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />
    Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br />
    Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

    if (file_exists("projekte/".$projektKurz."/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      $report .= $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " existiert schon! ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "projekte/".$projektKurz."/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      $report .= "Gespeichert unter: projekte/".$projektKurz."/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  $report .= "Ungueltige Datei!";
  }
  header("Location: projectupload.php?PNO=$PNO");
```

I have been using this code for about 3 years now without any problems. Now suddenly I have problems with the upload. Pdfs don't upload anymore. Pictures work, doc (older MS Word), docx, xlsx work as well.

So far I have set higher permissions (777), added the additional mime types for pdf (previously I only had application/pdf) and tried to change the owner of the folders but nothing has fixed the problem.

The file size is not a problem, I have uploaded 50 MB files before and now even a 44kb pdf-file is rejected.

I couldn't find any recent changes to the mime types that would explain this issue online either.

I had the same problem with docx, xlsx and pptx, but that got fixed once I inserted the mime types of these newer documents (even tho it worked before with the mime types of the older doc, xls and ppt as well).

When I try to upload a pdf file now I get returned:

```
Ungueltige Datei!
```

I'm out of ideas and hope you guys have some more ;)

**UPDATE1:**

As suggested I have activated the var_dump on top and it gets me this:

```
object(mysqli_stmt)#2 (10) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(0) ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["param_count"]=> int(1) ["field_count"]=> int(4) ["errno"]=> int(0) ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["error_list"]=> array(0) { } ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "00000" ["id"]=> int(1) }

string(0) ""
```

Comment: _"I have a problem suddenly with code that worked perfectly"_ **Code doesn't just stop working**, something changed that affected the code and caused it to stop functioning.

Comment: Hehe, yeah, probably. But the only thing that might have changed is the php-version of the server I would guess.

It's now running:

    PHP Version 5.4.42
    MySQL Version 5.5.43

Comment: Upgrading to a new php version can and most likely is the cause of your errors. The larger the upgrade the more is changed.

Comment: Are PHP-Error and warning messages activated? If not, activate it and check if there are errors or notices. (Also check the source-code of the browser page). Where does $_FILES come from? There might be a problem filling that variable. Do a var_dump to check. While debugging you should temporary comment out the header-forwarding in the last line

Comment: With the var_dump (taking away the // on top) I get: SEE EDIT "UPDATE1" ABOVE!

Comment: I did not mean, you should do a var_dump on the mysqli-object. You should do it on the $_FILES-array! `var_dump($_FILES);` I guess it's probably empty.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably in this case `$_FILES["file"]["type"]'s` value is an `empty` string for some reason.

When uploading a file it's better to make the check for an error `$_FILES["file"]["error"]` at the very beginning. If its value equals `0` then continue with the file type check, otherwise return an appropriate message error.

[Here you can find the possible error values](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)